# Undefined reference when compiling C++ project with pocketsphinx and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, undefined-reference, pocketsphinx

I recently have installed pocketsphinx and opencv, I created and compiled sample projects with both of those libraries and both worked fine.
Then I tried creating a project where I would use both, but compiling has become a pain.

I don't think it has anything to do with my current problem but there first was some conflicting type declaration. I solved that by modifying sphinx's `prim_type.h` file as following:

```
#if !defined(int64) && !defined(int64)
// If other dependencies use those, prevents conflicting declaration
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
typedef __int64          int64;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64;
#elif defined(HAVE_LONG_LONG) && (SIZEOF_LONG_LONG == 8)
typedef long long int      int64;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
#else /* !HAVE_LONG_LONG && SIZEOF_LONG_LONG == 8 */
typedef double          int64;
typedef double          uint64;
#endif /* !HAVE_LONG_LONG && SIZEOF_LONG_LONG == 8 */
```

The first if wasn't there at first, I added it such that there would be no problem if I first imported opencv adn THEN sphinx in a file needing both dependencies.

I then tried to compile the following code (which is the pure opencv code I used to test out opencv)

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"


#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "body_parts_detection/detectBodyParts.h"


using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture capture(0); // capture video from webcam
    Mat frame, prevFrame;
    
    while( true )
    {
        // Capture the current frame from the input video stream
        capture >> frame;
        
        // Downsample the input frame for faster processing
        float downsampleFactor = 0.5;
        resize(frame, frame, Size(), downsampleFactor, downsampleFactor, INTER_NEAREST);
        
        // Apply the classifier to the frame depending on the enabled macros
        if( !frame.empty() )
        {
            detectEyes(frame);
        }
        
        else
        {
            cout << "No captured frame. Stopping!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        
        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; }
    }
    
    capture.release();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Btw `body_parts_detection/detectBodyParts.h` is the header file of the following project that I imported: https://github.com/prateekvjoshi/Body-Parts-Detection, note that the main function also comes from this project.

Now when I try to compile this giving the compiler only the opencv libraries, that is, using the following command:

> g++ main.cpp ./body_parts_detection/*.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

where `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` gives me :

-I/usr/include/opencv -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab
-lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_datasets -
lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -
lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_video -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -
lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -
lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_viz -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_ximgproc -
lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -
lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -
lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core`

It, as I said previously, works totally fine!
But when I try to add pocketsphinx libraries to the mix, with the following command:

> g++ main.cpp ./body_parts_detection/*.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv pocketsphinx`

where `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv pocketsphinx` gives me

-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -I/usr/local/include/pocketsphinx -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -I/usr/include/opencv -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_video -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_viz -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lpocketsphinx -lsphinxbase -lsphinxad -lpulse -lpulse-simple -lpthread -lm

Then, suddenly, it doesn't work anymore and I get `undefined reference` errors (keep in mind this is a pure opencv project, there are no pocketsphinx dependencies):

```
/tmp/ccVDpw8s.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectFace(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x4d3): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectEyes(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x681): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x6d0): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0xc82): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectEars(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0xea9): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0xef8): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x1637): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectMouth(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x185e): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x1cbd): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectNose(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x1e5a): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x22b9): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectSmile(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x2456): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x28b5): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectUpperBody(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x2a52): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x2d0c): undefined reference to `cv::rectangle(cv::Mat&, cv::Rect_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x2d61): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectLowerBody(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x2ee1): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x3340): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `detectFullBody(cv::Mat)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x34dd): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(cv::String const&)'
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text+0x393c): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x4d): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccbZxpo9.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
detectBodyParts.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

**EDIT**
It's the libs part that seem to cause trouble. I could keep the result of pkg-config with --cflags ofpocketsphinx as long as the --libs flag only came with opencv

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: try specifying `--cflags` and `--libs` separately. g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv pocketsphinx` main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --libs opencv pocketsphinx`

Comment: @Waqar unfortunately it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: You probably have an incomplete and/or outdated version of `opencv` installed in `/usr/local`, which `pocketsphinx` diverts to. Try to specify separately `--cflags --libs opencv --cflags --libs pocketsphinx` (in this order). I personally always install every local package under its own prefix, e.g. `--prefix /usr/local/pocketsphinx`, so as to create no interference between packets.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. That doesn't work either. I compared the results of `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv pocketsphinx` and `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv --cflags --libs pocketsphinx`. They are exactly equal.

Comment: Sorry I meant `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) $(pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx)`, two separate pkg-config commands. Anyway, if you have a broken opencv in /usr/local/lib, you better remove it.

Comment: That was my first solution but it doesn't work. Guess I'll reinstall opencv and see what happens